# How can I tell whether a class/interface is a mock with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nsubstitute

I'm trying to port some code that I wrote using the FakeItEasy library to a project that is using NSubstitute.

One requirement that I have is an assertion check that the Serilog logger factory has been mocked already. To do this in FakeItEasy the code is:

`if (!Fake.IsFake(myVariable)) {Error()}`

However I can't see anything obvious in the NSubstitute calls to do the same kind of thing, and nothing stands out in the documentation (and I can't think of a sensible Google query involving `NSubstitute` `test for mock` that won't return 1000's of false positives)

Comment: Maybe check if the type name starts with `Castle.Proxies`?

Comment: NSubstitute will create a wrapper class around the object. NSubstitute uses Castle proxy to create objects so other way to do it would be to check if mockObject.GetType().Namespace == "Castle.Proxies". Probably a more robust way is to compare types for objects and interfaces. Assuming you have an object. For objects you can do `mockObject.GetType().BaseType == baseType.GetType()` for interfaces you can do `mockObject.GetType() == typeof(ObjectProxy)`

Comment: Thanks both - was hoping to not need to do type checking across 2 libraries (even if NSubstitute isn't likely to move away from Castle.Proxies), it just feels a bit nasty and fragile. I'm suspicious that there may not be a nicer way around it though.

Comment: Please see discussion here: https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/659